# Code print on browser (Firefox)

Tags: java, jsp, firefox

[image]

I am using this code to make user login form the issue is I am able to login from Internet Explorer but when I login from Firefox this same code prints the HTML version of the code on the screen.

This code prints the pending list after login:

```
 <%@ page language = "java" import="java.util.Iterator"  import="java.util.ArrayList"     import="java.lang.*" contentType = "text/html; charset = ISO-8859-1"
     %>
<%@ page errorPage="/error.jsp" %>
<%    
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
    //session = request.getSession(false);
    //               session.invalidate();
    //             session = request.getSession(true);
 %>




<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html>
     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>All Pending List </title>
         <style type="text/css">
            <!--
             @import"Image/cssmenuvertical.css";
             -->


          </style>

          <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
          <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
          <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>    
          <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3"/>
          <meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page"/>


          <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">


             function goToURL()
              {
                window.location="logout.jsp";

             }
             function bck()
            {
                window.history.forward();

            }
              setTimeout("bck()",0);
              </script>
              <title>All Pending Details</title>
         </head>

      <body bgcolor="lightblue">


         <% String val="for upload";
          session.setAttribute("val", val);
          %>
          <%            
              if (session.getAttribute("aa") != null) {

          %>
         <%            
             String findval = "find validation";
             session.setAttribute("findval", findval);%>
          <form id="form_id" action="" method="" >
              <table id='table1' align="center" >
                 <tr>
                     <td style="background-image: url(Image/header.jpg); width: 800px; height:           40px" color="lightblue"></td>
                      </tr>
                       <tr>
                         <td>

                         <ul id="navmenu">
                             <li><a href="#">Find ></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="Find_ip.jsp">By IP </a></li>
                                   <li><a href="find_mac.jsp">By Mac Address </a></li>
                                <li><a href="find_date.jsp">By Date </a></li>
                                <li><a href="find_email.jsp">By Email </a></li>
                                <li><a href="find_approve">By Approved </a></li>
                                <li><a href="find_remove">By Removed </a></li>
                                 <li><a href="find_reg.jsp">By Registration ID</a></li>


                            </ul>
                        </li>



                        <li><a href="AlluploadedForms">| Uploaded Forms ></a></li>

                        <li>  <a href="logout.jsp">| Logout ></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><br/>
        <center>
            <FONT COLOR="#0000FF" size="4"><b>All Pending List</b></FONT>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </center>
        <center>
            <TABLE cellpadding="15" border="1" style="background-color: #C2DFFF">
                <th ><FONT COLOR="#0000FF">Registration NO.</FONT></th>
                <th><FONT COLOR="#0000FF">Administrator Name</FONT></th>
                <th><FONT COLOR="#0000FF"> Email</FONT></th>
                <th><FONT COLOR="#0000FF"> Division Name</FONT></th>
                <th><FONT COLOR="#0000FF"> Registration Date</FONT></th>

                <%                        


                    ArrayList all = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("values");
                    Iterator i = all.iterator();
                    while (i.hasNext()) {
                        String t = (String) i.next();


                        out.println(t);

                    }


                %>

            </TABLE>
            <table><tr><td>
                        <input type="button" name="logout" value="Logout" onclick="goToURL();"/></td></tr></table>

            <%} else {
                    response.sendRedirect("logout.jsp");


                }%>

        </center>
    </form>
    <center><FONT COLOR="#0000FF"> Government Of India<br/>
            Ministry Of Communications and Information Technology<br/>
            Department of Information Technology </FONT></center>
</body>
```

After login on that page from Firefox

Comment: what is the url you are trying to access ?

Comment: Thanks satya
https://msgapp.nic.in/relay/login.jsp

Comment: can you link some screenshot so that it will be clear what exactly getting printed in mozilla?

Comment: Thanks Ravindra
After putting login and password its printing the code in HTML but its working fine on interne explorer

Comment: This might be a silly question, but are you sure you're accessing the same URL in both browsers? Could it be possible that in Mozilla youve actually loaded the .jsp file from the filesystem and not via the webserver?

Comment: @YagyavalkBhatt I understood that. Can you post the screenshot after login?

Comment: Crollster Thanks 
I am using webserver

Comment: Thanks Ravindra i have uploaded the image

Comment: @YagyavalkBhatt Any exception in the server console?

Comment: Thanks Ravindra no exception in server console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will happen when the content is been interpreted as `text/plain` instead of as `text/html`. That can only mean that the HTTP response `Content-Type` is been set to `text/plain`, or is broken, or is missing.

Check the HTTP response headers with a HTTP traffic checker. If you have [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) installed, then press F12 and check *Net* tab. The `Content-Type` header must say at least `text/html`. This is by default already the case. Perhaps you've some `Filter` which is doing its job wrong.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you are not consistent with specifying the response character encoding in the JSP code as initially posted in your question. You're specifying ISO-8859-1 in the HTTP response header and you're specifying UTF-8 in the HTML meta head. This makes no sense. This should however not cause this kind of problem.

By the way, "Department of Information Technology" and then that oldschool style of writing JSPs full of deprecated HTML elements and poor practices...? Is this a hobby site or something?

Answer (score -1):

I tried logging in and can see the code working fine , getting Administrator Not valid error as per this image :

[image]

Comment: Satya what version are you using since it can be version issue ,but i cant find the issue in my code relating version,but after you login on this page it shows the above code in HTML

Comment: An image with no text is not helpful.

Comment: just now checked on ff12.0 as well , can see the page intact

Comment: Satya Thanks but as you see i can go to that page but after login it ,it works fine as desired on internet explorer but when i login from mozilla it shows the above screenshot check my post screenshot

Comment: tested and can see it working perfectly fine as per the screenshot in my answer